# multiprocessing.Pool.map() 'MaybeEncodingError: Error Sending Results' while trying to scrape a long list of links

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, python-multiprocessing

This is all of my code: (I am working in a jupyter notebook)

- I just tried to do something new with the `worker` function and I am still getting a `Reason: 'RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')'` error. I tried to implement `itertools` like so:

> ```py
> def worker(links):
>    # row_data = [meeting_data_scraper(link) for link in links]
>    with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as p:
>        row_data = p.map(meeting_data_scraper, links)
>        all_data = set(it.chain.from_iterable(row_data))
>    return all_data
> ```

and this gave me the same error I have been getting. I just do not understand why this is not working. I know I am probably missing something simple but I can't see it and I am losing my mind.

> ```py
> import csv
> import requests
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
> import pandas as pd
> from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
> from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
> import itertools as it
>
> # this is where any files or directories/path variables go:
> csv_filename = './meetings.csv'
> ```

> ```py
> def csv_parser(csv_reader, header: str):
>    _header = next(csv_reader)
>    headerIndex = _header.index(header)
>    # now create an empty list to append the addresses to
>    data_list = []
>    # loop through CSV file and append to address_list
>     for line in csv_reader:
>         all_data = line[headerIndex]
>         data_list.append(all_data)
>     return data_list
> ```

> ```py
> # CREATE A CSV WRITER TO WRITE ROW DATA TO A NEW CSV FILE WITH MEETING > > DETAILS:
> def csv_writer(csv_writer, data):
>     # Open CSV file to append data to:
>     with open('new_meeting_data.csv', 'w') as f:
>         csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, field_names=list(data.keys()))
> ```

> ```py
> # create func to get list of links:
> def get_links(csv_filename):
>     with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
>         csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
>         link_list = csv_parser(csv_reader, 'link')
>     return link_list
> ```

> ```py
> # CREATE A FUNCTION THAT WILL EXTRACT ADDRESS DATA FROM EACH LINK IN 
> # LINK LIST:
> def get_address_data(soup):
>         try:
>             address_tag = soup.address
>             address = address_tag.contents[1]
>             
>             meeting_name = soup.find(
>                 'div', class_='fui-card-body').find(class_='weight-300')
>             name = meeting_name.contents[1]
>             
>             city_tag = meeting_name.find_next('a')
>             city = city_tag.contents[0]
>             
>             state_tag = city_tag.find_next('a')
>             state = state_tag.contents[0]
>             return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': city, 'state': state}
>
>         except IndexError as ie:
>             print(f"Index Error: {ie}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': city, 'state': 'state'}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': 'city', 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': 'address', 'city': city, 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': 'name', 'address': address, 'city': city, 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
> ```

> ```py
> # CREATE A FUNCTION THAT WILL EXTRACT ALL THE TABLE DATA FROM EACH LINK
> # IN THE LINK LIST. THE TABLE DATA WILL THEN NEED TO BE PARSED AND 
> # CLEANED IF THERE ARE MULTIPLE ITEMS:
> def get_table_data(soup):
>         try:
>             info_table = soup.find('table', class_='table fui-table')
>             # obtain all the columns from <th>
>             headers = []
>             for i in info_table.find_all('th'):
>                 title = i.text
>                 headers.append(title.lower())
>
>                 # now create a dataframe:
>             df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
>
>         
>             # Now create the foor loop to fill dataframe
>             # a row is under the <tr> tags and data under the <td> tags
>             for j in info_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
>                 # if info_table.find_all('tr')[1:] == AttributeError.NoneType:
>                 #     print("No info table found")
>                 row_data = j.find_all('td')
>                 row = [i.text for i in row_data]
>                 length = len(df)
>                 df.loc[length] = row
>
>             # data['day'].append(df['day'].to_list())
>             # data['time'].append(df['time'].to_list())
>             # data['info'].append(df['info'].to_list())
>             day = df['day'].to_list()
>            time = df['time'].to_list()
>             info = df['info'].to_list()
>
>             # now return data
>             return {'day': day, 'time': time, 'info': info}
>         
>         except AttributeError as ae:
>             print(f"info_table.find_all('tr')[1:] raised error: {ae}")
>             return {'day': 'day', 'time': 'time', 'info': 'info'}
> ```

> ```py
> # CREATE A FUNCTION THAT WILL PARSE THE ROW DATA AND STORE IT 
> # IN A DICTIONARY. THAT DICTIONARY CAN THEN BE INSERTED INTO 
> # A LIST OF DICTIONARIES CALLED ROW_LIST BUT TO DO THIS THE PARSER
> # HAS TO JOIN LIST ITEMS INTO ONE LONG STRING SO EACH ROW HAS THE 
> # SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS:
> # THIS WAS INSERTED INTO meeting_data_scraper
> def meeting_row_parser(item0, item1):
>     """
>     :param item0: This is the address data in a dictionary. Use the following keys to access
>     the data -> Keys: 'name' - 'address' - 'city' - 'state' 
>     :param item1: This is the meeting details data in a dictionary. Use the following keys to
>     access the data -> Keys: 'day' - 'time' - 'info'
>     
>     create a final dictionary that will be used to store the information in the database as one row. 
>     I will need to join the list items to create one string with a | seperating each item so I can 
>     split the string when retrieving the data.
>     """
>     try:
>         row = {}
>         try:
>             row['name'] = item0['name']
>             row['address'] = item0['address']
>             row['city'] = item0['city']
>             row['state'] = item0['state']
>             # now add item1 to the row data
>             row['day'] = ' | '.join(item1['day'])
>             row['time'] = ' | '.join(item1['time'])
>             row['info'] = ' | '.join(item1['info'])
>             # now return the row data dictionary
>             return row
>         except Exception as e:
>             print(f'{e}')
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(f'{e}')
>         for k, v in row.items():
>             if v is not None:
>                 pass
>             else:
>                 v = str(k)
>         return row
> ```

> ```py
> # THIS IS THE 'MAIN LOGICAL FUNCTION' THIS FUNCTION WILL COMBINE THE 
> # get_address_data, get_table_data, and meeting_row_parser FUNCTIONS.
> # THAT WAY I CAN EXECUTE ALL OF THE FUNCTIONS IN ONE CALL.
> def meeting_data_scraper(link):
>     
>     def get_address_data(soup):
>         
>         try:
>             address_tag = soup.address
>             address = address_tag.contents[1]
>             
>             meeting_name = soup.find(
>                 'div', class_='fui-card-body').find(class_='weight-300')
>             name = meeting_name.contents[1]
>             
>             city_tag = meeting_name.find_next('a')
>             city = city_tag.contents[0]
>             
>             state_tag = city_tag.find_next('a')
>             state = state_tag.contents[0]
>             return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': city, > 'state': stat> e}
>             
>         except IndexError as ie:
>             print(f"Index Error: {ie}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': city, 'state': 'state'}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': address, 'city': 'city', 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': name, 'address': 'address', 'city': city, 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>             try:
>                 return {'name': 'name', 'address': address, 'city': city, 'state': state}
>             except UnboundLocalError as ule:
>                 print(f"UnboundLocalError: {ule}")
>              
>     def get_table_data(soup):
>         try:
>             info_table = soup.find('table', class_='table fui-table')
>             # obtain all the columns from <th>
>             headers = []
>             for i in info_table.find_all('th'):
>                 title = i.text
>                 headers.append(title.lower())
>
>                 # now create a dataframe:
>             df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
>
>         
>             # Now create the foor loop to fill dataframe
>             # a row is under the <tr> tags and data under the <td> tags
>             for j in info_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
>                 # if info_table.find_all('tr')[1:] == AttributeError.NoneType:
>                 #     print("No info table found")
>                 row_data = j.find_all('td')
>                 row = [i.text for i in row_data]
>                 length = len(df)
>                 df.loc[length] = row
>
>             # data['day'].append(df['day'].to_list())
>             # data['time'].append(df['time'].to_list())
>             # data['info'].append(df['info'].to_list())
>             day = df['day'].to_list()
>             time = df['time'].to_list()
>             info = df['info'].to_list()
>
>             # now return data
>             return {'day': day, 'time': time, 'info': info}
>         
>         except AttributeError as ae:
>             print(f"info_table.find_all('tr')[1:] raised error: {ae}")
>             return {'day': 'day', 'time': 'time', 'info': 'info'}
>
>     def meeting_row_parser(item0, item1):
>         """
>         :param item0: This is the address data in a dictionary. Use the following keys to access
>         the data -> Keys: 'name' - 'address' - 'city' - 'state' 
>         :param item1: This is the meeting details data in a dictionary. Use the following keys to
>         access the data -> Keys: 'day' - 'time' - 'info'
>         
>         create a final dictionary that will be used to store the information in the database as one row. 
>         I will need to join the list items to create one string with a | seperating each item so I can 
>         split the string when retrieving the data.
>         """
>         row = {}
>         try:
>             row['name'] = item0['name']
>             row['address'] = item0['address']
>             row['city'] = item0['city']
>             row['state'] = item0['state']
>         except Exception as e:
>             print(e)
>             row['name'] = 'name'
>             row['address'] = 'address'
>             row['city'] = 'city'
>             row['state'] = 'state'
>
>         # now add item1 to the row data
>         row['day'] = ' | '.join(item1['day'])
>         row['time'] = ' | '.join(item1['time'])
>         row['info'] = ' | '.join(item1['info'])
>
>         # now return the row data dictionary
>         return row
>     
>     # STEP 1: Get the webpage response obj from requests
>     page = requests.get(link)
>     
>     # STEP 2: Get Soup object for html parsing
>     soup = bs(page.text, "lxml")
>
>     # Create two dicts with the following keys
>     address_dict = get_address_data(soup)
>     details_dict = get_table_data(soup)
>
>     d = [address_dict, details_dict]
>     row_data = meeting_row_parser(d[0], d[1])
>     
>     return row_data
> ```

### `multiprocessing.Pool` functions

> ```py
> # THE MAIN FUNCTION. THIS WILL BE USED WITH THE POOL.MAP METHOD
> # TO ATTEMPT TO EXTRACT ALL THE DATA FROM THOSE LINKS QUICKER 
> # AND MORE EFFICIENTLY. THIS IS THE 'WORKER'
> def worker(links):
>     # row_data = [meeting_data_scraper(link) for link in links]
>     row_data = meeting_data_scraper(links)
>     return row_data
> ```

> ```py
> # Create a Pool Factory function to determine thread or process
> def pool_factory(key, n):
>     if key == 'proc':
>         print('using procs instead of threads')
>         return Pool(n)
>     else:
>         return ThreadPool(n)
> ```

> ```py
> def main():
>     """
>     :description: This will execute the logic for scraping the link_list
>     from the meetings.csv file. It also brings together the Pool.map
>     method to make scraping easier and faster.
>    
>     :csv_filename: in import cell top of file
>     
>     :info: To change from using 'processes' just change 'proc' 
>     in pool_factory to 'thread'
>     """
>     link_list = get_links(csv_filename)
>     pool = pool_factory('proc', 10)
>     results = pool.map(worker, link_list[:1000])
>     pool.close()
>     pool.join()
>     data = [len(x) for x in results]
>     return data
> ```

> ```py
> data = main()
> ```

> That is the complete codebase. I know it is a lot but I wanted to make sure everything was there. I have tried for three days different solutions and nothing is working. I tried without functions, I tried asyncio, I tried using concurrent.futures' ThreadPoolExecutor. Nothing seems to work.

#### THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE:

---

```bash
using procs instead of threads
Index Error: list index out of range
Index Error: list index out of range
Index Error: list index out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MaybeEncodingError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/blackbox/projects/github/web-scraper/scraped_meeting_data/meeting_data_nb.ipynb Cell 13' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 main()

/home/blackbox/projects/github/web-scraper/scraped_meeting_data/meeting_data_nb.ipynb Cell 12' in main()
     12 link_list = get_links(csv_filename)
     13 pool = pool_factory('proc', 10)
---> 14 results = pool.map(worker, link_list[:1000])
     15 pool.close()
     16 pool.join()

File /usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py:364, in Pool.map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    359 def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
    360     '''
    361     Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    362     in a list that is returned.
    363     '''
--> 364     return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

File /usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py:771, in ApplyResult.get(self, timeout)
    769     return self._value
    770 else:
--> 771     raise self._value

MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[{'name': ' Contoocook Keep It Simple Group', 'address': ' 24 Maple St ', 'city': 'Hopkinton', 'state': 'New Hampshire', 'day': 'Sunday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Wheelchair Access, Speaker, Discussion, Concurrent with Al-Anon'}, {'name': ' Triangle Group Online', 'address': ' 401 Southwest Plaza', 'city': 'Arlington', 'state': 'Texas', 'day': 'Monday | Saturday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm | 9:00 am - 10:00 am', 'info': 'Big Book, Open Meeting | Big Book, Open Meeting'}, {'name': ' AA Happy Thoughts Group', 'address': ' 1330 Hooksett Road ', 'city': 'Hooksett', 'state': 'New Hampshire', 'day': 'Thursday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Discussion, Virtual'}, {'name': ' Esperanza De Vivir', 'address': ' 2323 West Lincoln Avenue', 'city': 'Anaheim', 'state': 'California', 'day': 'Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday', 'time': '8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm', 'info': 'Spanish | Spanish | Spanish | Spanish | Spanish | Spanish | Spanish'}, {'name': ' Discussion Anaheim', 'address': ' 202 West Broadway', 'city': 'Anaheim', 'state': 'California', 'day': 'Wednesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Sunday', 'time': '12:00 pm - 1:00 pm | 5:30 pm - 6:30 pm | 5:30 pm - 6:30 pm | 12:00 pm - 1:00 pm | 5:30 pm - 6:30 pm', 'info': 'Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting | Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting | Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting | Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting | Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting'}, {'name': ' In the Hall Group', 'address': ' 50 Westminster Street  ', 'city': 'Walpole', 'state': 'New Hampshire', 'day': 'Monday | Wednesday | Friday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm | 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm | 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Discussion | Discussion | Discussion'}, {'name': ' Shining Light Group', 'address': ' 162 Village Road ', 'city': 'Newbury', 'state': 'New Hampshire', 'day': 'Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday', 'time': '8:30 am - 9:30 am | 8:30 am - 9:30 am | 8:30 am - 9:30 am | 8:30 am - 9:30 am | 8:30 am - 9:30 am', 'info': 'Wheelchair Access, Discussion | Wheelchair Access, Discussion | Wheelchair Access, Discussion | Wheelchair Access, Discussion | Wheelchair Access, Discussion'}, {'name': ' Carry The Message', 'address': ' 727 South Harbor Boulevard', 'city': 'Anaheim', 'state': 'California', 'day': 'Saturday', 'time': '6:00 am - 7:00 am', 'info': 'Open Meeting'}, {'name': ' Chester Big Book Group', 'address': ' 1 Chester Street ', 'city': 'Chester', 'state': 'New Hampshire', 'day': 'Wednesday', 'time': '8:00 pm - 9:30 pm', 'info': 'Big Book'}, {'name': ' Bills Babes Womens Book Study', 'address': ' 311 West South Street', 'city': 'Anaheim', 'state': 'California', 'day': 'Thursday', 'time': '6:30 pm - 7:30 pm', 'info': 'Closed Meeting, Women'}, {'name': ' Big Book Study', 'address': ' 202 West Broadway', 'city': 'Anaheim', 'state': 'California', 'day': 'Monday', 'time': '8:30 pm - 9:30 pm', 'info': 'Wheelchair Access, Open Meeting'}, {'name': ' Saturday Night Live', 'address': ' 2759 South King Street ', 'city': 'Honolulu', 'state': 'Hawaii', 'day': 'Saturday', 'time': '8:00 pm - 9:00 pm', 'info': 'Discussion, English, Open Meeting, Speaker, Virtual'}, {'name': ' Pali Womens Group', 'address': ' 2747 Pali Highway ', 'city': 'Honolulu', 'state': 'Hawaii', 'day': 'Thursday', 'time': '5:30 pm - 6:30 pm', 'info': 'Discussion, English, Open Meeting, Women, Virtual'}, {'name': ' Ohua Group', 'address': ' 310 Paoakalani Avenue ', 'city': 'Honolulu', 'state': 'Hawaii', 'day': 'Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday', 'time': '7:30 pm - 8:30 pm | 7:30 pm - 8:30 pm | 7:30 pm - 8:30 pm | 7:30 pm - 8:30 pm | 7:30 pm - 8:30 pm | 7:30 pm - 8:30 pm', 'info': 'English, LGBTQ, Newcomer, Open Meeting, Virtual | Discussion, English, LGBTQ, Open Meeting, Speaker, Virtual | English, LGBTQ, Open Meeting, Virtual | English, LGBTQ, Open Meeting, Step Meeting, Virtual | Discussion, English, LGBTQ, Literature, Open Meeting, Virtual | Big Book, English, LGBTQ, Open Meeting, Virtual'}, {'name': ' New Beginnings Womens Meeting', 'address': ' 5919 Kalanianaʻole Highway ', 'city': 'Honolulu', 'state': 'Hawaii', 'day': 'Tuesday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Big Book, Child-Friendly, English, Newcomer, Women, Virtual'}, {'name': ' Malia Discussion', 'address': ' 766 North King Street ', 'city': 'Honolulu', 'state': 'Hawaii', 'day': 'Thursday', 'time': '7:30 pm - 9:00 pm', 'info': 'Discussion, English, Open Meeting, Speaker, Virtual'}, {'name': ' Huntsville Group', 'address': ' 309 Church Avenue ', 'city': 'Huntsville', 'state': 'Arkansas', 'day': 'Wednesday | Saturday', 'time': '8:00 pm - 9:00 pm | 8:00 pm - 9:00 pm', 'info': 'Closed Meeting | Open Meeting'}, {'name': ' Squad 26 Group', 'address': ' 1415 6th Avenue', 'city': 'Anoka', 'state': 'Minnesota', 'day': 'Thursday', 'time': '7:30 pm - 8:30 pm', 'info': 'English'}, {'name': ' Squad 23 Anoka', 'address': ' 2700 North Ferry Street', 'city': 'Anoka', 'state': 'Minnesota', 'day': 'Sunday', 'time': '7:30 pm - 8:30 pm', 'info': 'Open Meeting, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Squad 20 Anoka', 'address': ' 2700 North Ferry Street', 'city': 'Anoka', 'state': 'Minnesota', 'day': 'Saturday', 'time': '8:00 am - 9:00 am', 'info': 'Men, Closed Meeting, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Saturday Night Fever', 'address': ' 1631 Esmeralda Place ', 'city': 'Minden', 'state': 'Nevada', 'day': 'Saturday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Open Meeting, Discussion, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Squad 2 Anoka', 'address': ' 2700 North Ferry Street', 'city': 'Anoka', 'state': 'Minnesota', 'day': 'Tuesday', 'time': '8:00 pm - 9:00 pm', 'info': 'Child-Friendly, Open Meeting, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Squad 18 Anoka', 'address': ' 2700 North Ferry Street', 'city': 'Anoka', 'state': 'Minnesota', 'day': 'Wednesday', 'time': '6:30 pm - 7:30 pm', 'info': 'Open Meeting, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Language of the Heart', 'address': ' 850 West 4th Street ', 'city': 'Fallon', 'state': 'Nevada', 'day': 'Wednesday', 'time': '5:15 pm - 6:15 pm', 'info': 'Open Meeting, Discussion, Wheelchair Access'}, {'name': ' Speaker and Birthday Meeting', 'address': ' 457 Esmeralda Street ', 'city': 'Fallon', 'state': 'Nevada', 'day': 'Saturday', 'time': '7:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'info': 'Birthday, Open Meeting, Speaker, Wheelchair Access'}]'. Reason: 'RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')'
```

- I just need to be able to go through the entire list of links (which is 33, 488) get the page contents, and extract the name, address, and info table data. I then want to put the extracted data into a dictionary and append that dictionary to a list so that each dictionary will be like a row. so I can then add the data (each dict) to a csv row.

I tried to do a for loop and use the `meeting_data_scraper` function, scraping one link at a time and it ran for 2 1/2 hours and then had a connection error. But this is not the first time I have had issues like this. I can never get my code to scrape big lists.